# Reopen SQLiteOpenHelper when my application is stopped as "close()" was never explicitly called on database"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. When my application is normally closed, the database is closed normally in the method `onDestroy()`, too. When it's force closed, the database is left open and later, when my application tries to read the database using `getReadableDatabase()`, it crashed with the following message:

> `09-26 13:45:30.995: ERROR/Database(12632): close() was never explicitly called on database`

Here is the full LogCat:

```
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/myApplication/databases/DownloadDatabase1' 
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
09-27 03:10:04.331: ERROR/Database(391):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
```

I followed the stack trace and I guess the exception is because of the following line of code:

> `setLocale(Locale.getDefault());`

Th code above is from the file [SQLiteDatabase.java](http://hi-android.info/src/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java.html). Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: please post the entire logcat

Answer (score 2):

Even though it gives that error, you should be able to access the database. Looking at the underlying code, my understanding is that such an error shouldn't cause your program to exit:
http://hi-android.info/src/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java.html

Check the `finalize()` method there. You will see, it just tries to clean up, it doesn't throw exception.

You must have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: yes. due to the stack trace I think exception occurs in the constructor of SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend closing the database as soon as you are done working with it.  Opening and closing the database each time you need to preform a transaction is not a bad idea either.  Unless your application is constantly writing data, you shouldn't lose performance

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the issue however since the application could be force closed when the database is in use.

Comment: I think their must be something else going on.  I've had my application FC many times before closing the database.  It shouldn't keep you from opening it back up.  I get that error message also but it is never causes a crash.  Make sure your scanning the entire logcat for the exception

Comment: my application downloads several files from a web server and I'm using sqlite to save my downloads state and progress. so I have a lot of update query per download, and I think it's not efficient to open and close database for each query.
howover I tried this idea, but I don't know how to open database after I close it.
I'm using sqliteOpenHelper, and it opens the database implicitly when I call getReadableDatabase or getWritableDatabse. but when I explicitly close it, calling getReadbleDatabse will cause an exception that the databse is closed before.
thanks for your answer!